# Why the web page is not refreshing my value, when I use Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-scraping

I am simply trying to get any Facebook page amount of *likes*, and to show it in a simple web page. I used BeautifulSoup to scrape the amount of *likes*.

But the problem is: once the script is running the value are not being refreshed... is there any way to re-run the script periodically?

This is the *.py* script

```
      from flask import Flask, render_template

        import requests
        import string
        import lxml.html
        import lxml.html.clean
        import unicodedata
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import re


        user = 'EttounsiyaTV'
        url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'+ user
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
        fe = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': '_4-u3 _5sqi _5sqk'})
        f = fe.text
        nonBreakSpace = u'\xa0'
        soup = f.replace(nonBreakSpace, '')

        soup = re.sub("\D","",soup)

        fan_number = int(soup)
        old_number = 6206360
        difference = old_number - fan_number


        print("lost in one day {difference} ".format(difference=difference))

        print(fan_number)


        app = Flask(__name__)



        @app.route("/")
        def home():
            return render_template("index.html",text=soup,text2=f)


        if __name__ == "__main__":
            app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is the *html* which is found in templates

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"/>

      <head>
           <title>Flask app</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


      </head>
      <body>
       <center> <h1> {{ text }}</h1> <center>

      </body>
    </html>
```

How to upload this on free host, and make it refresh every 5 seconds or something?

Comment: Why not using the API to perform a similar task?

Comment: facebook won't allow you to use api to see number of likes

Comment: https://www.coregenie.com/how-to-get-facebook-likes-count-of-a-page-using-graph-api-2-8-ver/

Comment: This method is working. Tested on 1/5/2017

Comment: No offense, @amir but... Do you trally think that people using Facebook data in 2019 are scraping it?

Comment: https://youtu.be/rcaDol0BdQc

Comment: @Pitto , facebook is blocking the access of different facebook pages likes !! 
that's why i am using the scraping method , so i can get , number of likes of any public facebook page :)